# where my library get installed in this makefile. how to change location of installed headers and .so.0 files

Tags: c, makefile

so I have simple Makefile

```
# SPDX-License-Identifier: (GPL-2.0)
CC := gcc

all: common_params.o common_user_bpf_xdp.o common_libbpf.o

CFLAGS := -g -Wall

LIBBPF_DIR = ../libbpf/src/
CFLAGS += -I$(LIBBPF_DIR)/build/usr/include/  -I../headers
# TODO: Do we need to make libbpf from this make file too?

common_params.o: common_params.c common_params.h
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c -o $@ $<

common_user_bpf_xdp.o: common_user_bpf_xdp.c common_user_bpf_xdp.h
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c -o $@ $<

common_libbpf.o: common_libbpf.c common_libbpf.h
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c -o $@ $<

.PHONY: clean

clean:
    rm -f *.o
```

so what is CFLAGS. it looks like it just global something. certainly some kind of Make related environment variable

SO i AM assumning when I run make command my libbpf installs in directory /home/fawad/bpf/xdp/libbpf/Makefile directs to real location of libbpf.

So I am assuming when I run program then my system look for libbpf headers in /home/fawad/bpf/xdp/libbpf/src/build/usr/include/ directory

So am I getting it right.. but if I want to specify the location of my libbpf `.so` file then is there anything I can do like changing this Makefile some how may be specify `-L /usr/lib/x86-64/usr/` so what ever shared libraries will be installed with this makefile be installed in /usr/lib/x86-64/usr directory, or do I need to change individual makefiles of libarries source makefile

Comment: This makefile doesn't build any .so files, just a few .o files. Normally you want to install custom libraries into `/usr/local/lib`, not `/usr/lib`.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat yes it does not build .so file. But it sure invokes src directory in libbpf thats build it. So I like to know where headers installed

Comment: Adding that dir to CFLAGS doesn't build anything. It just tells the compiler to look for headers in `$(LIBBPF_DIR)/build/usr/include/`.

Comment: ***certainly some kind of Make related environment variable*** no, it's just a variable, you can name it any way you want.

Comment: If you want to know what make will do, run `make`.  Those are the commands you've told make to run.  It doesn't run any other commands.  You'll see, it doesn't create any `.so` file and it doesn't copy any files anywhere.  It simply compiles those three object files.  Before you can have your makefile do something else, you need to decide what it is you want it to do.  If you were going to perform these actions from the shell prompt, what commands would you run?  Once you know that, you can tell make how to run those same commands.

Comment: @user786, no, `make`, when operating in conjunction with the makefile presented, *does not* invoke anything that builds a `.so` file, either.  Perhaps you are being confused by `$(LIBBPF_DIR)`.  That is just an expansion of the `LIBBPF_DIR` variable.  Recipes in `make` rules contain snippets of shell code, but makefiles are not shell scripts.